# what does sentience mean in the given context

Tags: meaning

[**Before we give doors and toasters sentience**, we should decide what we're comfortable with first.](http://www.newstatesman.com/sci-tech/2015/02/we-give-doors-and-toasters-sentience-we-should-decide-what-were-comfortable-first) Please explain the bold part.

Comment: someone please explain this

Comment: We need some more information about what you're asking. Where did this sentence come from? Are you having trouble with the word "sentience" or the phrase as a whole?

Comment: http://www.newstatesman.com/sci-tech/2015/02/we-give-doors-and-toasters-sentience-we-should-decide-what-were-comfortable-first

Comment: not getting the meaning of sentience in the given context

Answer (score 2):

*Sentient* means "responsive to or conscious of sense impressions; aware" ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentient)). In other words, sentient things are aware of their environment and can react to that environment in some way.

A sentient door, for example, might recognize someone and open the door to him or her, or refuse to open the door to a stranger. A sentient toaster might be able to detect when a piece of bread inside it is getting burnt.

By asking what we're comfortable with when it comes to sentient appliances, we're basically asking "How 'smart' do we want our appliances to be? What decisions do we feel comfortable allowing them to make?" For example, some people may not feel comfortable about a sentient door that chooses who is allowed to pass through it; they would rather make that decision themselves. They want the convenience of sentient appliances, but they probably don't want them to have *too* much control over things.

Basically, we want Siri, but we don't want Skynet.

Comment: Personally I think even Siri is a little too far gone. I'd be perfectly content to stop at heuristic spam filters. But +1 for a good answer.

Comment: Personally, I would distinguish between *true sentience* (which so far only some biological organisms possess) and *simulated sentience* or *apparent sentience* (the faked intelligence and/or intuition that certain appliances have been programmed with). Fortunately, there is still a long way to go before truly sentient machines are a reality (or at least, I bloody well hope so!). However, +1 for a good response to the OP's question.

Comment: +1 It is a platonic distinction, but *responsive* to stimuli is not precisely *sentient*.

Comment: @ScotM I was uncomfortable with the broader definition of _sentient_ used above, but M-W does include "**responsive to** or conscious of sense impressions; aware". AHDEL, Collins and RHK Webster's only have the 'consciously aware' sense, which I'm happier with.

Comment: @Erik Kowal The Talking Toaster was the most intelligent conversationalist on _Red Dwarf_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - And also in many households that have never heard of *Red Dwarf*.

Comment: Agreed, @EdwinAshworth, descriptively the distinction I wish to draw is compromised, yet positioned strategically between ***sense impressions*** at Goose Green and ***stimuli*** at Darwin, I vigorously wage my prescriptive battle for sentient creatures :-)

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if Merriam-Webster added the "responsive to" in addition to the "conscious of" in _sentient_'s definition precisely because people were using the word to describe appliances like this, so they adjusted the meaning to match the use.